# javascript get element in table untill a class happen

Tags: javascript

I have a huge table which most of the entries are "display:none". When the user click on an entity the rows should appear until the same class happen.

The table looks something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="1" class="department"></tr>
    <tr style="display:none;" id="43" class="sub"></tr>
    <tr style="display:none;" id="55" class="sub"></tr>
    <tr style="display:none;" id="85" class="sub"></tr>
    <tr id="6" class="department"></tr>
    <tr style="display:none;" id="150" class="sub"></tr>
</tbody>
```

So by clicking on id = 1 row the table should expand to show id= 43,55,85 (until reach to class="department" again)

I know it's a bit confusing so feel free to ask me questions if you need more explanation.

Comment: `$(".departement").click(function(){ $(this).nextUntil('.departement').show(); });`

Comment: I would prefer pure javascript rather than JQuery if possible

Comment: While playing with this I discovered that IE 9 can't handle IDs that start with a number (which was invalid until HTML5) when using querySelectorAll.

Comment: @RobG - that figures.  IE is such that party crasher.  Anyway, good to know.  I long knew that IDs starting with a digit were out of spec before HTML5, but I assume it was only because of the automatic global variables that map to them - I didn't know `querySelectorAll()` couldn't handle them.  An even better reason to warn people not to start IDs with a digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In plain javascript, you can do something like this:

```
function hasClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    var testCls = " " + cls + " ";
    return(str.indexOf(testCls) != -1) ;
}


var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        rows[index].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            for (var i = index + 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var row = rows[i];
                if (hasClass(row, "department")) {
                    break;
                }
                row.style.display = "";
            }
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Dh3p3/

The code uses a closure to capture the row index for each row, such that when it is clicked on, you can use that index into the previously captured array of rows. It then walks down that array showing rows until it finds an item that has the "department" class.

FYI, this puts event listeners on all the rows so if you manually show one of the hidden rows, it can be clicked on and have the same behavior.  If you only want click handlers on the `class="department"` rows, the code can easily be modified to do that too.

---

Here's a version that works with a hierarchy of classes.  It expands only items at the next level on a click:

function hasClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    var testCls = " " + cls + " ";
    return(str.indexOf(testCls) != -1) ;
}

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        rows[index].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // nothing to do if clicking on the last item
            if (index + 1 >= rows.length) {
                return;
            }
            // get class name to stop on
            var clsToStopOn = this.className;
            // get class name to show
            var clsToShow = rows[index + 1].className;
            for (var i = index + 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var row = rows[i];
                if (hasClass(row, clsToStopOn)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (hasClass(row, clsToShow)) {
                    row.style.display = "";
                }
            }
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Working multi-level demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9HgPt/

Comment: Well there are more than 2 level in the table, so if click on department then sub department opens if they click on sub department category opens and so on. I know how to take care of that though.

Comment: @kou - I coded it for the HTML example you provided - didn't know you wanted multiple levels.  If you need any further help, let me know.

Comment: Thanks. I ll just wanted to know how to read, until the next class. I will store the class of the clicked row in a variable and substitute the "department" with the variable. I ll let you know if didn't work.

Comment: @kou - I added a multi-level version too.